# RHEL 9 - Upgrading authselect causes overwrite

Tags: rhel, ldap

I've been configuring my system to use the desired `/etc/nsswitch`, `/etc/authselect/system-auth` and `/etc/authselect/password-auth` configuration including SSSD to access my LDAP server.
After running a `dnf update` it seems like this configuration is overwritten and I lose access to my system with a LDAP user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you picked one of the default configurations and then modified it. The files in directory `/etc/authselect/` are assumed by `authselect` to be copies of (or symlinks to) the corresponding files of the currently active profile, and they are supposed to be replaceable at any time from the respective source profile.

You should not have modified these files directly in any case; if you had modified the actual files in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and `/etc/pam.d` instead of the versions symlinked to `/etc/authselect/`, then the `authselect` command would have been able to detect the files as locally modified, and wouldn't have replaced them unless a specific `authselect --force` option was used.

The other option would have been to create your own custom profile, and actually it looks like you actually were already pretty close to achieving that: you should have placed your customized `system-auth`, `password-auth` and `nsswitch.conf` files into a sub-directory of `/etc/authselect/custom`, together with a mandatory `README` file, whose first line becomes the description of your custom profile in `authselect list` output. See `man 5 authselect-profiles` and `man 8 authselect`.

You could also see if `/var/lib/authselect/backups` contains an useful backup.

If it does, create a directory `/etc/authselect/custom/ldap`, restore the configuration files in there, write a README file (apparently just one line for description is enough), then run `authselect select ldap` to activate it.

Afterwards, when you need to modify the configuration, modify the files in `/etc/authselect/custom/ldap`, then run `authselect apply-changes -b`, and it will automatically keep a backup of the old configuration for you.

Comment: Thank you @telecoM . I've come to learn that you're not allowed to update the default configuration of authselect as you point out in `/etc/authselect/system-auth`. This has to be done through a custom profile.

Comment: I've tried to use a custom profile and upgraded a new system, and I still lose ldap access. Somethings happens with the `/etc/authselect/*` when `dnf update` is run.